# Convert pdf to text using perl

Tags: perl, pdf, text

I have a pdf file that I would like to convert to a text file.
I tried perl perl getpdftotext.exe fileName.pdf on a linux command line but nothing happens.
I tried `CPAN CAM::PDF` and no luck.

I get the error Use of uninitialized value in string eq at

`C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/CAM/PDF.pm line 2362`

and the output file is empty.

I am able to read the number of pages in the pdf file.
`my $num=$pdfone->numPages();` returns the correct number of pages.
I am using Adobe Reader X version 10.1.4.
I also tried a renderer, trying to get one page...2nd snippet
I also get the error unintialized value. I have tried different pdf files.
I am using Strawberry perl.

`enter code here`

```
use CAM::PDF;
use CAM::PDF::PageText;
use PDF::API2;
    my $pdfone = CAM::PDF->new('WFServlet.pdf');
    my $outfile = "pdfWFServeltRESULT.txt"; 
    my @lines;
    open (OUTF, ">$outfile") || die "Can not open $outfile";

    for my $page (1 .. $pdfone->numPages()) {
       my $text = $pdfone->getPageText($page);
       @lines = split (/\n/, $text);
    }
    :
    : #snippet 2
 use CAM::PDF;
 use PDF::API2;
 use CAM::PDF::PageText;
 :
 my $pageone_tree = $pdfone->getPageContentTree(1);
 my $doc->getPageText(1);
 if (defined $doc) {
    print OUTF CAM::PDF::PageText->render($doc);
 }
 if (defined $pageone_tree) {
    print OUTF CAM::PDF::PageText->render($pageone_tree);
 }
```

Comment: Been there. Then, I discovered [pdftohtml](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/). See "[Scraping PDF documents without losing your sanity](http://www.nu42.com/2014/09/scraping-pdf-documents-without-losing.html)".

Comment: Thank-you for the poppler suggestion. Never heard of it. I will try it tomorrow when I am at home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try Apache Tika.](https://tika.apache.org/download.html) I just started using it to pull text for a small search engine I'm developing. So far it's been pretty nice.

The perl code goes like this...

```
my $text = `java -jar /some/path/tika-app-1.8.jar --text '/some/file'`
```

Comment: #!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;

my $tika = "C:/Apache_tiki";
chdir $tika;
my $here = getcwd();
print "Current directory: $here\n";
my $myfile="Example.pdf";
my $text=`java -jar tika-app-1.9.jar --text "$myfile"`;
print "Text: $text\n";

Comment: [Text::PDF2XML](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::PDF2XML) is available as a simple wrapper around Tika and a couple of other extraction libraries.

Answer (score 5):

I'm the author of CAM::PDF and I heartily recommend using a different tool for this task. :-) I wrote the text extraction as a fun experiment and quickly discovered that it's a very hard problem to get right.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you would like to use Perl? There are many other pdftotext tools that you can use, which will do this job better. Try poppler-utils. One of the best pdf conversion tools available.

Comment: CAM::PDF was a nice effort. The Apache-tiki is working fine. What I like about it is that it can be called within a perl script.